# How can I access Apache server (that runs on Ubuntu) from VirtualBox OSE to test my php websites?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, php

I should test php websites on ie6,ie7,ie8 but i have ubuntu.

My computer have OS Ubuntu and virtual box OSE.

In ubuntu I run apache server that running my websites with special config.

How can I access from virual box OSE to apache server (that run on ubuntu) for testing my php websites?

Thanks

Comment: There's no specific reason to test a PHP site with any particular OS.  The PHP is all handled by the web server and HTML rendered to the client.

Comment: However, the PHP will at some point generate HTML/CSS, which then must be checked with multiple browsers (if one is careful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key question is - how is the network of your guest configured?  The usual choices are NAT, Bridged or Host Only (though there's also Internal).  Which you chose will make a difference to how you progress.  The following assumes that you've got one physical interface.

### NAT/Bridged

Point the web browser at the LAN IP of the Apache server (if you're not sure what that is, check the output of `ip addr show eth0`)

### Host Only

Point the web browser at the IP of the Host Only interface on the Host.  If you're not sure what that is, check the output of `ip addr show eth`).

Comment: You're right, but perhaps it wasn't obvious to you that Yosef is running both VirtualBox and Apache on the same box.  You might want to edit your answer to explain how to network to the VB host from a VB guest.

Comment: I running apache on my OS UBUNTU and not on virtual box